# only one particle showing in the scene with three.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js

I am trying to create a sphere with particles randomly floating on its surface. It will move depends on the position on mousemove.
something like this [image]

Strangely, it is only displaying one particle on canvas. I am debugging with `console.log(vertices)`, but it clearly shows all the `vertices` in the array.

[My code in CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/trusting-lucy-we5wym?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with your loop. You're assigning a value to `theta` and `phi` only once outside your loop, then you give the same value to all 1600 vertices:

```js
const theta = Math.acos(THREE.Math.randFloatSpread(2));
const phi = THREE.Math.randFloatSpread(360);

for (let i = 0; i < 1600; i++) {
  const vertex = new THREE.Vector3();

  vertex.x = distance * Math.sin(theta) * Math.cos(phi);
  vertex.y = distance * Math.sin(theta) * Math.sin(phi);
  vertex.z = distance * Math.cos(theta);

  vertices.push(vertex.x, vertex.y, vertex.z);
}
```

When you use `console.log(vertices)`, look at the `x, y, z` values and you'll see they all repeat.

What you should do is re-assign a new `theta` and a new `phi` **inside** the loop, so each vertex gets a unique position:

```js
let theta, phi;
let x, y, z;

for (let i = 0; i < 1600; i++) {
  theta = Math.acos(THREE.Math.randFloatSpread(2));
  phi = THREE.Math.randFloatSpread(360);

  x = distance * Math.sin(theta) * Math.cos(phi);
  y = distance * Math.sin(theta) * Math.sin(phi);
  z = distance * Math.cos(theta);

  vertices.push(x, y, z);
}
```

You also don't need to create a `THREE.Vector3()` on each iteration, it's pretty inefficient to create 1600 `Vector3`s just to be discarded immediately. Instead you can re-use the same `x, y, z` variables to avoid all those object construction costs.

[See here for a working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-firefly-ehdsj0?file=/src/App.js) of your example. I also scaled down the point size to 1.

Answer (score 3):

Just a small remark, not the answer (all kudos to @Marquizzo)

Since `r133`, there is a method `.randomDirection()` of `THREE.Vector3()`, which helps us to set points on a sphere in a more convenient way.

Thus, all the code for instantiating of particles is:

```js
    const distance = Math.min(200, window.innerWidth / 16);
    let vertices = new Array(1600).fill().map((v) => {
      return new THREE.Vector3().randomDirection().setLength(distance);
    });
    const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(vertices);
    const material = new THREE.PointsMaterial({ color: 0xffffff, size: 1 });
    const particles = new THREE.Points(geometry, material);
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-gauss-t0cnnd)